# Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable

Tags: swift, macos

Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSWindow':

```
import Cocoa

class MyWindow: NSWindow {

init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask aStyle: Int, backing bufferingType: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
    super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask(rawValue: NSWindow.StyleMask.RawValue(aStyle)), backing: bufferingType, defer: flag)

    self.titleVisibility = .hidden
}


required init?(coder: NSCoder) { // error: Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable AND Failable initializer 'init(coder:)' cannot override a non-failable initializer
    super.init(coder: coder) // error: 'init(coder:)' is unavailable
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`NSWindow` does not support coding.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow#) You may not, and don't need to, implement `init(coder:)`. Just remove the method; you're not doing anything with it anyway.

Comment: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(contentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Is this a compile time error? A runtime error? What situation is leading to it?